# What is the difference between verknittern, zerknittern e zerknüllen?

Tags: meaning

All these words seem to have the same meaning. Are they synonyms?

Comment: In the current form I tend to close this question, since the top level can be answered by a dictionary and no details for a finer level are given.

Comment: Although @HenningKockerbeck already gave a good general answer -- if you're looking for the right word to use in an actual context, you could probably get better help by providing that context.

Answer (score 4):

All three verbs are similar, meaning to crease something or to crumple something. But there are different intensities or connotations.

"Verknittern" means to crumple something a bit. If you "verknittern" a shirt, for example, the shirt is no longer flawless and pristine, but the damage isn't that big. Maybe you just need to re-iron the shirt.

"Zerknittern" implies more severe damage, maybe even up to making the shirt unusable. The prefix "zer-" has often connotations of destruction, deconstruction, dismantlement, see "zerstören", "zerlegen", "zerschneiden", "zerbeißen", "zerdrücken" etc.

"Zerknüllen" is related to the verb "knüllen" or "zusammenknüllen", which means to crumple something into a ball, to scrunch something up. There is an idea of compaction with most varations of "knüllen". "Zerknüllen" combines the "destructiveness" of "zer-" with the compaction of "knüllen".